# Testear conexión local a servidor virtual de mysql

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, virtualbox

Saludos comunidad.
He instalado un servidor virtual (`Virtual Box`) de `Mysql` Sobre `Ubuntu Server` en mi computador que corre con Windows 10.. la cuestión es que me gustaría poder probar la `conexión` al servidor desde mi windows y no tengo ni idea de QUE NECESITO y cómo hacerlo.. con un simple SELECT * FROM "tabla" para ver registros ya estaría bueno (Y)!..

Ty!

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que abrir un cliente de Mysql, conectarte a la IP y puerto del servidor virtual. Probablemente ahí tengas que armar una regla para abrir y/o forwardear el puerto desde la aplicación que estés usando para virtualizar.
Conectandote así debiera ser suficiente para lo que quieres comprobar.

Comment: Amigo entiendo perfectamente que es lo que hay que hacer.. lo que no se es COMO hacerlo... Pero gracias por el dato (Y)

Comment: Por el COMO, a que te refieres? a como abrir las conexiones? como configurar el virtualizador? a que?

Comment: Pues si.. ya lo descubri.. tenia que configurar el virtual para que tome el mismo tipo de ip del anfitrión .. luego instalar el phpmyadmin en el servidor .. luego te logeas  desde un navegador en la maquina anfitrión con la ip que tiene la MV /phpmyadmin .. algo así .. 192.168.1.15/phpmyadmin .. Luego te sale la interfaz del phpmyadmin y pues te logeas con el usuario del servidor de base de datos que hallas configurado previamente .. normalmente 'root' y '123456' ...

Comment: Bueno, para redondear tu pregunta, en realidad tienes que abrir algún cliente de mysql y hacer lo mismo. Conectarte a la 192.168.1.15 y al puerto de mysql.